# Debug multithreaded program in X32dbg

Tags: debugging

I am still quite inexperienced in reverse engineering. I have a small program that establishes an HTTP connection to a server and send data via POST method to the servert. I see strings like Winhttp.dll, WinHttpOpen, WinHttpOpenRequest, etc. I have added breakpoints for all the commands I have found. However, the breakpoints never hit. I see that the program connects to the server and sends encrypted data via POST to the server. I see that the sample starts multiple threads. I'm guessing that I need to jump into the correct thread, right? If this is true, how do I do this in X32dbg? I this sample I have set breakpoint at 12345678 and abababab. These addresses are pseudo adresses.

```
12345678 | mov eax,sample.123343|String="winhttp.dll"
abababab | mov eax,sample.5B33E0|String="WinHttpOpenRequest"
...
```

Comment: hit ctrl+g type WinHttpOpen hit enter hit f2 to set bp on the function

Comment: Thanks, I will try.